# Chat Application using PHP; Code Correction

Tags: php, html

I am making an online chat application for my school.  I thought it would be cool for users to just switch between users from the same iframe, the box I used that displays msg.txt.  Well, it occurred to me that I could just make a form in html, and in php, have an if...else statement concerning the form, basically stating that "If word is received by the  'Aaron' form, Then switch $msg to $msg1."  However, it didn't work. What did I do wrong?  The code is displayed in a link.  The following is a small section of my code, the code I am focused on for this specific problem.  http://key-mail.zxq.net/sourcecode.txt

By the way, it was giving me an error having something to do with a T_STRING.  What is that?  I've searched the web and I can't quite figure it out.  Of course, I know what a string is, but I don't know what a T_STRING is or what the T stands for.

Answer (score 1):

You are not escaping your output. Instead of:

```
die(" ...
```

Do:

```
$html = <<<EOA
___ YOUR HTML GOES HERE
EOA;
die($html);
```